# How to read input from the user?

Tags: haskell, user-input

How to ask a user to give a number of 7 digits and define a
function which converts these digits into a list of individual Integers. The example:

```
toDigits (1234567) = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
toDigitsReverse 1234567 = [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

NB. (1234567) should be entered by the user.

I know how to prompt the user and the function to get it into an array but I do not know how to put them together. This is what I get so far - the function to separate them.

```
toDigits :: Integral x => x -> [x]
toDigits 0 = []
toDigits x = toDigits (x div 10) ++ [x mod 10]

main :: IO ()
main = do 
    putStr "The split array is "
    print(toDigits 1234567)
```

How to get the `todigit` function to accept input?

I also tried the following but it gives an error

```
toDigits :: Integer -> [Int]
toDigits n = map (\x -> read [x] :: Int) (show n)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Please enter the USI number: "
    usi <- getLine
    let usiasnumber = read usi :: Int
    print("The USI split into single digit array is " ++ toDigits usiasnumber)
```

I did this but its not working. Where am I going wrong? This is the error it is giving me

> Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘Char’ Expected type: [Char] Actual
> type: [Int]

Comment: StackOverflow is *not* a homework service. Make a fair attempt and come back
with *specific* questions about that attempt. See the
[*open letter to students with homework problems*](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Comment: What have you tried so far, are you able to read a number from input? And do you know how you would get `(123456, 7)` out of `1234567`

Comment: You can use [`readLn`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:readLn), see if this gets you started: `main = do n <- readLn; print (toDigits n)`.

Comment: `readLn` can read any `Read`-able type, in this case it defaults to `Integer`. You can be explicit about this by annotating `n :: Integer <- readLn` or enabling `{-# Language TypeApplications #-}` at the top of your file and writing `readLn @Integer`.

Comment: What does 'n' represent in this case?

Comment: `n` represents the number we read from input, to read a number from input and print it doubled you write `do n <- readLn; print (n * n)`. Take a look at the section on [Input and Output from Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output#hello-world).

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to get a number from the user is to actually get a string from the user, then convert it to a number. Going from there to digits is just about the same thing as converting back to a string. I therefore recommend that you just skip the intermediate step and go straight from string to list of digits. If you want to reverse the digits and print them back out, say, just do that:

```
import Control.Monad
main = putStrLn . reverse =<< getLine
```

If you are going to use the digits for something else, you may want them in number form rather than character form; `digitToInt` will do that for you.

```
import Data.Char
main = map digitToInt <$> getLine -- exercise for the reader: do somethin' with the digits
```

Comment: It sounds like you should write a function to map an Int to the list of its digits, and then use concatMap.

Comment: I need help with this
totalDigits :: [Integer] -> Integer
Example: totalDigits [1, 4, 3, 8, 5, 12, 7] = 1 + 4 + 3 + 8 + 5 + 1 + 2 + 7 = 31
I want a fuction to find the sum of each individual eement in a list. Like how the 12 split into 1 and 2 while adding th rest of elements together